# C++ dirent.h not working with in Docker container when the target directory is a volume

Tags: c++, docker, dirent.h, mounted-volumes

I'm working with a rather old program and one of the C++ plugins uses the dirent.h library to provide directory listing features to the program.

Strangely, it reads empty for Docker volumes mounted with `-v` and it's kind of got me stuck in a project. Is there anything I can do to resolve this? The only other solution I can think of is to mount the volume into a temporary directory then write a script to copy stuff over to a "normal" directory but this just feels really hacky and stupid.

Comment: Have you tried a symlink? I doubt it would work but probably worth a try

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped out and pointed me towards the `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` which disables the default security profile. I'm still not sure exactly which property was causing this behaviour so that would be a nice thing to know.

Anyway, the documentation is here for anyone else finding this via search: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/

Edit: does not work on Windows, still need a solution.